# Who and what is Him?

Tags: powerpuff-girls

In the PowerPuff Girls one of the strongest villains they face is Him, but his appearance, name, and voice are quite confusing. Who and what is Him?

[image]

Comment: I think most of your questions can be answered by http://powerpuffgirls.wikia.com/wiki/HIM ..

Comment: Yes, and if you find his voice and appearance confusing for a demon, note in particular the line in the "Trivia" section of Andrew Thompson's link which says *'His voice and mannerisms were inspired by the Chief of the Blue Meanies in The Beatles movie "Yellow Submarine".'* And if you don't want to watch the whole movie, just see [this clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2uCNd1AVJo) and see if you can note the resemblance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### HIM is the Devil.

Or more precisely, he's the Devil in the clothes of an androgynous cross-dresser, partly inspired by [this character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_Blue_Meanie) in the film [*Yellow Submarine*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063823/).

From the [Wikia page](https://powerpuffgirls.fandom.com/wiki/HIM_(1998_TV_series)):

> It is implied that he is the devil himself, or at least some form of demon, in The Powerpuff Girls series, he is said to be "so sinister, so evil, so scary, so horribly vile that his real name can never be said, lest fear be struck into the very hearts of men."
>
> [...]
>
> His voice and mannerisms were inspired by the Chief of the Blue Meanies in The Beatles movie "Yellow Submarine".
>
> His physical appearance is an amalgamation of sorts, borrowing a mix of concepts and imagery in regards to Satan with cross-dresser attire.

Comment: FWIW, sources for the Blue Meanies reference at https://www.cbr.com/powerpuff-girls-him-beatles-cartoon-yellow-submarine-subversive-villain/

Answer (score 1):

It was inspired in a nightmare of the creator Craig McCracken, I saw it in a Cartoon Network magazine.

Comment: Could you try and find the quote to [edit] in and back this up?

Comment: I need time, because I saw it a long time ago when I was a kid. I guess that I keep the magazine somewhere, I need to find it

Comment: @AlfredoVillegas: No worries. We're not going anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Him is the PPG embodiment of all fear (acording to my niece, a devout PPGs fan).

Comment: I don't suppose you have any better sources? Did they read that somewhere?